# MySQL, select rows where a parameter value depends on the value that it has in a different row

Tags: mysql

I have a table where I can find the same parameter in subsequent rows (See Example A). I need a query to select only the rows where the value is different from the previous row (See Example B), something like

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE Par(id)!=Par(id-1)
```

It shouldn't be difficult but I'm new to MySQL (and databases in general) and I haven't found an command or an example for this.

```
Example A       Example B
*********       *********
*ID *Par*       **ID*Par*
*********       *********
*1  * a *       *5  * a *
*2  * a *       *6  * g *
*3  * a *       *7  * f *
*4  * a *       *8  * d *
*5  * a *       *9  * f *
*6  * g *       *10 * h *
*7  * f *       *11 * j *
*8  * d *       *12 * f *
*9  * f *       *17 * f *
*10 * h *       *18 * d *
*11 * j *       *19 * s *
*12 * f *       *20 * g *
*13 * f *       *21 * t *
*14 * f *       *22 * g *
*15 * f *
*16 * f *
*17 * f *
*18 * d *
*19 * s *
*20 * g *
*21 * t *
*22 * g *
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t.id,t.par FROM your_table t
WHERE t.par <> 
    (SELECT par FROM your_table
     WHERE id = t.id + 1)
```

Comment: @Andrew: leo.vingi solution was wrong for your needs and, according to your examples, it doesn't work!! So, if that is good, your examples are not!! I simply don't understand...

Comment: the problem described here is a simplification of a larger problem. I described in more detail here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848063/error-code-2013-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-during-query, still a simplification. Your solution is working, and thank you for your effort, but it's difficult to extend it to the largest problem, because it takes too long to run! Relatively to this example, what I want to remove are the rows 1-4 and 12-16 (or 2-5 and 13-17). The command DISTINCT does this, but finally I used "GROUP BY". I will update the questions with the working code. Thanks

Comment: @AndrewStrathclyde: I understand and respect your decision. Anyway when you post a question you get answers for that question, not for others. Leo solution is absolutely wrong and is misleading for people coming here to learn something!! You shouldn't accept wrong answers, that's all.

Comment: that answer solve the problem, I'm wondering if maybe you have seen something else in the random letters that I used in the example (so that you were trying to catch a recurrence that was there by chance - when you said "look at example B with letter G). For the problem of the type of question, I tried to generalise the problem in order to make the answer easier and more useful, and I didn't wanted people to write the code for me. In future I will try to give more details to avoid this problems.

Comment: @AndrewStrathclyde: if you run `SELECT DISTINCT Par FROM table_name` you get only one "g" while there should be 3 (6, 20, 22), you get only one "f" while there should be 3 (7, 9, 12), you get only one "d" while there should be 2 (8, 18). Do you think that that query works for the question _select rows where a parameter value depends on the value that it has in a diferent row_? No, it does not. I'm sorry, but I can't really understand your point of view. I don't mind my "accepted answer" went away, but I do care that solution provided is wrong, definitely wrong, absolutely wrong for your questi

Comment: actually you are right, the question was different, and the GROUP BY works only because in the real table I have many more columns with different selection criteria, so that  the problem that you have pointed does not appear. My bad, the example was not well structured.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT DISTINCT Par
FROM table_name`

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Comment: @AndrewStrathclyde can you explain your solution/tweak because this answer doesn't answer your question as your example result set has duplicates in it.

Comment: @BenSwinburne: you too think this is wrong, I feel better. Thanks

Comment: @AndrewStrathclyde Indeed, example 2 has multiple, g, f, d, s in it... DISTINCT alone will _not_ produce this result

Comment: To be clear, even I think my solution was wrong for the question that was posted. ;) It was purely by chance that my solution worked for the actual problem the asker was trying to solve. Upvoted Marco's answer

Comment: I thank you @leo.vingi; it's important to me telling you that this discussion wasn't _against_ you!! You posted your solution, correct or wrong it doesn't matter. My point was to let OP understand that accepting a wrong answer could mislead people coming here to find a solution to a similar problem. Thanks again!! :)