# MySQL, query too slow, how to improve it?

Tags: mysql, timeout

## The problem

I'm running a query using Workbench 5.2.35 and a MySQL server 5.5 and I have the error "Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query" after 600.516 seconds also after little changes in the query. The query has two roles:

1. select a particular type of records characterised by having 'value1' in 'col1' (pass from Stage A to Stage B)
2. remove the records where the value in 'col2' is the same as the value in 'col2' of the next result (pass from Stage B to Stage C)

   ```
   Stage A             Stage B             Stage C
   ***************     ***************     ***************
   *ID *col1*col2*     *ID *col1*col2*     *ID *col1*col2*
   ***************     ***************     ***************
   *1  * A  * a  *     *3  * C  * a  *     *3  * C  * a  *
   *2  * B  * a  *     *7  * C  * f  *     *7  * C  * f  *
   *3  * C  * a  *     *8  * C  * f  *     *16 * C  * b  *
   *4  * S  * a  *     *9  * C  * f  *     *18 * C  * c  *
   *5  * B  * a  *     *16 * C  * b  *
   *6  * A  * g  *     *17 * C  * b  *
   *7  * C  * f  *     *18 * C  * c  *
   *8  * C  * f  *
   *9  * C  * f  *
   *10 * A  * f  *
   *11 * B  * f  *
   *12 * D  * f  *
   *13 * S  * f  *
   *14 * F  * f  *
   *15 * F  * f  *
   *16 * C  * b  *
   *17 * C  * b  *
   *18 * C  * c  *
   ```

and is a generalisation of:
[MySQL, select rows where a parameter value depends on the value that it has in a different row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839137/mysql-select-rows-where-a-parameter-value-depends-on-the-value-that-it-has-in-a)

The query is:

```
SELECT t.id, t.col2, t.col3, t.col4, t.col5 FROM tablename t
WHERE t.id < 1000000
    AND t.col1 = 'value1' 
    AND t.col2 <> 
    (SELECT col2 FROM tablename
        WHERE col1 = 'value1' 
        AND id > t.id 
        LIMIT 1);
```

## Reason for the error

Now, from this post 
https://serverfault.com/questions/29597/what-does-mysql-error-2013-mean
the causes of this error can be:

1. Someone KILLed the query
2. Network problems caused the connection to die
3. The server crashed/died
4. Your connection was idle for wait_timeout and was killed
5. The client wasn't pulling data fast enough for net_wait_timeout and was killed

but since the query stops at 600.516 seconds, I guess that the problem in this case is number 4 (timeout).

## Possible problems and solutions

The first idea would be to increase the wait_timeout time, but I think that this is triggered by a previous error: the query doesn't return anything but continues to run. The limit **t.id < 1000000** is used exactly to test the query in a reasonably limited subset (the database has about 200 millions of entries)
So, I'm thinking that there is some problem in the query, in particular in the passage between Stage B and Stage C (the previous step is trivial)

Any idea for the error or for the query will be much appreciated.

Thanks

---

## The solution

this is the working code, inspired by the best answer. The command DISTINCT work, but finally I used GROUP BY and ORDER BY in order to present the results in a better way.

```
SELECT id, col1, col2, ..., coln FROM tablename
    WHERE col1 = 'value1' 
    AND col2 = 'value2'
    ... 
    AND coln = 'valuen'
    GROUP BY col2
    ORDER BY id;
```

Comment: First of all what do u want from that query, its will time out ince it will traverse m*n rows
of both the queries, it has surely been time out. Better will be if u brief us ur requirement, so that v can help..

Comment: @SashiKant, I think the scope of the query is well described in the section "The Problem" and I would like to change the timeout limit only if strictly necessary, but I think the problem is in the query

Comment: +1 Nice and clear description. Although you could have just asked: My query runs for 600 seconds, how do I make it faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT DISTINCT Par FROM table_name`

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Comment: The DISTINCT command works, but finally I used GROUP BY and ORDER BY. It's much faster than the original query.

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite it using `not in` the query optimizer has a special case for that.
Also I would use a different trick to limit the number of results to one.

The problem with `limit` is that it first creates a temp table with **all** the results and than selects 1 row from that.

```
SELECT t.id, t.col2, t.col3, t.col4, t.col5 
FROM tablename t
WHERE t.id < 1000000
    AND t.col1 = 'value1' 
    AND t.col2 NOT IN 
    (SELECT col2 FROM tablename
        WHERE col1 = 'value1' 
        AND id = t.id+1)    <<--- assuming that `id` is the primary key.
```

If you have a compound index on (col1, col2) and use id as your primary key the query should not take forever.

Looking at your query, I'd rewrite it as:

```
SELECT t.id, t.col2, t.col3, t.col4, t.col5 
FROM tablename t
WHERE t.id IN ( 
  SELECT t2.id 
  FROM tablename t2
  WHERE t2.col1 = 'value1'
  GROUP BY t.col2)
```

This should do the trick, if I've studied the stages correctly.

Comment: :Using "in" or "not in" will again kill the query with a timeout

Comment: @SashiKant Did you read the full query, including the elimination of the limit clause? IMO this query should return pretty fast.

Comment: @Johan, thanks for the suggestion for the NOT IN, but the last row "AND id = t.id+1" won't work if you look at the values for id in the tables "Stage B" and "Stage C". Anyway I'll try with the end of my previous query and I'll see if it works

Comment: @AndrewStrathclyde, in that case you need to show the full query, but you can use `@var:= id+something` and then use @var somewhere else in the query to test against, the idea is to make sure only 1 row gets selected in the first place to prevent the horrible temp-table creation that mysql when using limit.

Comment: @AndrewStrathclyde, Updated the answer with a optimized query, how does that one run?

Comment: @Johan, so you think that LIMIT is the bottleneck. The problem is that the records are not spaced equally, but I can create a range. Thanks. - Pardon, it takes a while to run it!

Comment: @Johan, thank you for the help, but I managed to solve the problem using "GROUP BY", it does the job and it's very fast. I will update the question with the working answer. I think also you were right, the name of the question should be changed since it was more a problem of speed than an error, I'll see if I can change it when I edit the question. Thanks again